# Windows 7 style System Tray for Windows xp

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Is there any way to change my XP system tray so that opens like Windows 7 style system tray

**From XP Style :**

[image: windows xp style]

**To Windows 7 Style like this:**

[image]

Comment: Upgrade to Windows 7.

Comment: I have windows 7, i just want xp system tray to look like win 7 system tray when the hidden icons are opened

Comment: There is no such thing as a "system tray". It's called the "taskbar notification area".

Comment: @cody I think during the time of windows 98 the _taskbar notification area_ was referred to as [system tray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskbar#Taskbar_elements)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look around this site:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/SevenMize-Windows-XP-123284.shtml

The screenshots for it seem to show a system tray like what you're after. Might also want to take a look at:

http://www.askvg.com/transform-windows-XP-into-windows-7-without-using-customization-pack/

Comment: The first link says "In this case, the change is only a facade as hidden icons will continue to open XP style. " and i am already using those apps in the second link. It doesn't do the job